# ElasticSearch Query to retrieve only field values and not documents

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is it possible in ElasticSearch to retrieve only value not documents.. Like only particular field value should be returned not as document just value

Comment: Just changing de query DSL via plugin, need a lot of job :(

Comment: wouldn't  [source_filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html)  work ?